# Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build

Tags: c++, qt

So i downloaded Qt and am designing my first GUI, and now it wont compile, i keep getting an error that says:

```
Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build
```

I've searched around on the net but alot of it seems jargon, even the other Stack Overflow documents dont make any sense..

How do i set up a compiler for QT to use? I downloaded g++ compiler last night to use with Sublime Text 2, and that's working, so is there a way to make g++ work with Qt?

Thanks guys

Comment: If you don't tell us what you've found in terms of resources and what you didn't understand there, we can't help you (any answer would probably end up as confusing to you), and chances are this will be closed as a duplicate. (And read the docs!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I supposed you're using Windows ) 
If you downloaded Qt for Visual studio you need to install visual studio too. Then go to
**Tools -> Options -> Build & Run**
in Qt Creator and then, in **Compilers** tab **add new** compiler.

Comment: Ah right, turns out i did download VS Qt... does the Mingw release require any extra software, or does it come with a built in compiler?

Comment: @amartin94 ~> I'm not sure, I've been using Qt for VS for years.

Comment: @amartin94 Mingw Qt obviously needs MinGW compiler suite.